# Wordpress add search filter

Tags: wordpress, filter

I want to filter posts by date where i can select multiple dates. ie 2013 & 2014.

I had been using a plugin called [annual archive](http://plugins.twinpictures.de/plugins/annual-archive/) but this only allows you to select one, 2013 or 2014.

I've used a plugin to allow me to execute php from the text widget, so I've created a form with checkboxes and appropriate date ranges etc but wasn't sure where to send it to, so I sent a get request to a new file i made in my theme (so it wouldn't 404 and i could locate it).
I managed to process the query parameters and run a query_posts() call to get the posts. In this file, I copied a template file from my theme and now it generates with my posts.

My url is however, /wp-content/theme/.. etc which is not ideal.

The posts are all under categories, could I redirect to the /category/x page but get it to use the posts i've already found?

Is there a better way of doing things because this feels really hacked but I couldn't find a better way..

Edit: Seems like using 
`add_action('pre_get_posts', 'my_func');
function my_func($query){  $query->set('year', 2014); }` in functions.php
is the way to go. Now I just need to figure out how to do year 2013 or 2014...

Edit 2: `$query->set('date_query', [['year' => 2014], 'relation' => 'OR', ['year' => 2012]]);`

Comment: @David This isn't about query_posts vs wp_query vs get_posts.

Comment: so what is your question? you can't redirect to another page load and retain php values, so you need to store them somewhere, but whats the point when you can create a new page where you want it and run the query there?

Comment: I currently have done that in, except in a script in the theme folder. My question was is there a better way? Ie if i'm filtering /category/x  could I send some query parameters to this url and handle this processing whilst keeping my url format. You're suggesting that I handle all of this on a new page, ok, but there's still the problem of this new page being under /wp-content/theme/silk/newfile.php. If I add a page for /search how do i map this to my script as the default action is to show page content straight from db

Comment: your permalinks decide this, for example, postname (2nd last option) the page name will be after your server name. But if you want something custom, add_rewrite_rule will handle this. But are you creating a page and it is listed /wp-content/theme/silk/newfile.php? that sounds a bit odd for wp filesystem what are your permalinks set at? // if you want to modify all querys check out pre_get_posts hook